# GeoServer 2.21 WPS request with output format application/json throws error

Tags: geoserver, wps

Since I upgraded GeoServer from 2.20.5 to 2.21.1 I get an error with WPS requests if I use application/json as output format:

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>gs:Unique</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                <wps:Body>
                    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2"
                        xmlns:training="http://localhost:8180/trainingserver/">
                        <wfs:Query typeName="training:openbaar_fruit"/>
                    </wfs:GetFeature>
                </wps:Body>
            </wps:Reference>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>attribute</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>a_lat_naam</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
    </wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:ResponseForm>
        <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
            <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
        </wps:RawDataOutput>
    </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 https://versie4.kaartviewer.nl/trainingserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>An error occurred while encoding the results of the process</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Error logging:

```
    10 022 09:22:20 INFO   [geoserver.wps] - 
2Request: getServiceInfo
310 022 09:22:20 INFO   [geoserver.wps] - 
4Request: execute
5    service = WPS
6    version = 1.0.0
7    baseUrl = http://localhost:8180/trainingserver/
8    identifier:
9        value = gs:Unique
10    dataInputs:
11        input[0]:
12            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@1440efa4 (value: features, codeSpace: null)
13            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@18695864 (body: net.opengis.wfs.impl.GetFeatureTypeImpl@29feae64 (handle: null, service: WFS, version: 1.0.0, baseUrl: null, providedVersion: null, extendedProperties: {}) (maxFeatures: null, outputFormat: GML2, resultType: <unset>, traverseXlinkDepth: null, traverseXlinkExpiry: null, formatOptions: null, metadata: null, startIndex: null, viewParams: null), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wfs, method: POST, mimeType: text/xml, schema: null)input[0]:
14            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@4e5bb590 (value: attribute, codeSpace: null)
15            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@5df55e30
16    responseForm:
17        rawDataOutput:
18            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@f8d8792 (value: result, codeSpace: null)
19            mimeType = application/json
2010 022 09:22:20 WARN   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream could not be aborted in time. An error has occurred and could not be sent to the user.
2110 022 09:22:20 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
22org.geoserver.wps.WPSException: An error occurred while encoding the results of the process
23  at org.geoserver.wps.response.ExecuteProcessResponse.writeComplex(ExecuteProcessResponse.java:227)
24  at org.geoserver.wps.response.ExecuteProcessResponse.write(ExecuteProcessResponse.java:190)
25  at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1006)
26  at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
27  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
28  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
29  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
30  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
31  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
32  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
33  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
34  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
35  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
36  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
37  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
38  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
39  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
40  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
41  at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:357)
42  at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:176)
43  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
44  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
45  at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
46  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
47  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
48  at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
49  at org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:144)
50  at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
51  at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
52  at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
53  at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
54  at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
55  at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
56  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
57  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
58  at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
59  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
60  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
61  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
62  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
63  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
64  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
65  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
66  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
67  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
68  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
69  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
70  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
71  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
72  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
73  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
74  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
75  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
76  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
77  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
78  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
79  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
80  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
81  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
82  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
83  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
84  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
85  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
86  at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
87  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
88  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
89  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
90  at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
91  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
92  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
93  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
94  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
95  at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
96  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
97  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
98  at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
99  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
100 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
101 at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
102 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
103 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
104 at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
105 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
106 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
107 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
108 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
109 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
110 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
111 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
112 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
113 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
114 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
115 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
116 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
117 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
118 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
119 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
120 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
121 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
122 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
123 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
124 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
125 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
126 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
127 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
128Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
129 at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONWriter.reprojectGeometry(GeoJSONWriter.java:300)
130 at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONWriter.writeFeature(GeoJSONWriter.java:230)
131 at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONWriter.write(GeoJSONWriter.java:186)
132 at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONWriter.writeFeatureCollection(GeoJSONWriter.java:453)
133 at org.geoserver.wps.ppio.GeoJSONPPIO$FeatureCollections.encode(GeoJSONPPIO.java:79)
134 at org.geoserver.wps.CDataEncoderDelegate.encode(CDataEncoderDelegate.java:45)
135 at org.geoserver.wps.response.ExecuteProcessResponse.writeComplex(ExecuteProcessResponse.java:225)
136 ... 104 more
137 Suppressed: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Current context not Array but Object
138     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._reportError(JsonGenerator.java:2710)
139     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeEndArray(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:358)
140     at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONWriter.close(GeoJSONWriter.java:344)
141     at org.geoserver.wps.ppio.GeoJSONPPIO$FeatureCollections.encode(GeoJSONPPIO.java:80)
142     ... 106 more
```

If I do this with output format 'text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.1' I get a good response back:

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:Unique</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:training="https://versie4.kaartviewer.nl/trainingserver/">
            <wfs:Query typeName="training:openbaar_fruit"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>attribute</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>a_lat_naam</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.1">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Response:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection>
    <feature:boundedBy>
        <feature:Null>unknown</feature:Null>
    </feature:boundedBy>
    <feature:featureMember>
        <feature:UniqueValue feature:id="fid--78cd413f_183e4f9f885_-7fad"/>
    </feature:featureMember>
    <feature:featureMember>
        <feature:UniqueValue feature:id="fid--78cd413f_183e4f9f885_-7fac">
            <feature:value>Pyrus communis</feature:value>
        </feature:UniqueValue>
    </feature:featureMember>
    <feature:featureMember>
        <feature:UniqueValue feature:id="fid--78cd413f_183e4f9f885_-7fab">
            <feature:value>Prunus domestica</feature:value>
        </feature:UniqueValue>
    </feature:featureMember>
    <feature:featureMember>
        <feature:UniqueValue feature:id="fid--78cd413f_183e4f9f885_-7faa">
            <feature:value>Prunus avium</feature:value>
        </feature:UniqueValue>
    </feature:featureMember>
    <feature:featureMember>
        <feature:UniqueValue feature:id="fid--78cd413f_183e4f9f885_-7fa9">
            <feature:value>Malus domestica</feature:value>
        </feature:UniqueValue>
    </feature:featureMember>
    <feature:featureMember>
        <feature:UniqueValue feature:id="fid--78cd413f_183e4f9f885_-7fa8">
            <feature:value>Juglans regia</feature:value>
        </feature:UniqueValue>
    </feature:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Is there something new for WPS in this version or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The base error `Current context not Array but Object` indicates there is an issue in the input and it can't be encoded as GeoJSON (with the new GeoJSON encoder anyway) - I would try getting the output as raw text or GML to see what it looks like and add that to the question.

Comment: I updated the request with output format 'text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.1' and then it works. Is there something new for WPS with output format 'application/json' in this version or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It could be a bug, but the only way to tell is to attach a debugger and find out why the parser is expecting an Array but gets an Object in the JSON, I don't see anything in the GML that could be an Array. - One possible issue is that GeoJSON expects a geometry to be included in the feature?

Comment: Seems that is a bug - https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7246) with writing out GeoJSON without a geometry in the underlying GeoTools library. This is now fixed so your process should work in all builds of GeoServer produced after 2022-10-21.